# Can I upload photos but not post to wall in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Can I upload photos using Facebook API but not post to wall in Facebook?

What I use is the photos.upload in the API.

If it cannot be avoided, is there any way to delete that wall post so that I don't have to do it manually?

Comment: Not a right place to ask such questions.

Comment: @Prasoon: He's asking about Facebook API, why wouldn't SO be a valid place? There are something like 700 questions tagged as facebook here.

Comment: It is a programming question. He's asking if there's a way to upload photos to Facebook via the Facebook API without posting to the wall.

Comment: The question is changed. It's about the facebook API.

Comment: Prasoon responded before the OP edited his question.  It originally made no mention of the API, hence the 3 votes to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer my own question:

It's about the permission problem. We can set the permission so that the photos do not publish to wall.

Comment: ... but you can't do that on a photo upload by photo upload basis, as far as I know - you have to set that as blanket permission for the entire application, among the list the user is shown at the 'grant permission' screen, right?

Answer (score 5):

Documentation of graph API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) mentions the following:

> If you would like to suppress the
>   story that is automatically generated
>   in the user's feed when you publish a
>   photo (usually because you plan on
>   generating your own), you can add a
>   no_story=1 parameter. In this case,
>   the user will receive a notification
>   that your application has uploaded a
>   photo.

Adding the same parameter to the legacy REST API seems to work for me

Comment: It has been deleted from the documentation, don't know why, but it still works for Photos upload, on users or fan pages.