# Is it possible to upload a photo to fanpage album without publishing it?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Here on my [fanpage](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Power-Photo-Uploader/269434846409322) I've added my small app, that makes it possible, that fans can upload photos to a special photo album of this fanpage.

It's possible, cuz I use a fanpage admin permission ("manage_pages, publish_stream and offline_access").

But now - everytime someone uses this app, I get a photo publish news feed on my fanpage. How can I add a photo to a fanpage WITHOUT publish it to the newsstream?

Actually my publish php code looks like:

```
<?php
  $post_data = array(
    'image' => ('@' . realpath($photo)),
    'message' => $msg)
  );

  $facebook->setAccessToken(_FANPAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN);
  $data = $facebook->api('/'. _ALBUM_ID . '/photos', 'post', $post_data);
?>
```

When I remove the "publish_stream" permission with my fanpage admin account - there will appear a 'funny' bug. The uploaded photo won't show up in the photo album and not in the news stream. But it is in the photo-strip where you see all new photos and when you click on it, it will be in a row with all those uploaded photos... it looks like, that it is somewhere in a 'hidden' photoalbum.

**So does anyone have a clue, how to post photos over the graph api without publish it to the news stream?**

Thanks in advance,
Jurik

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the solution! Nowhere in the docs is it mentioned - if you don't want post a feed when you upload a photo via Graph API set following parameter: no_story=1

This information was earlier here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

But somehow it disappeard from this doc. :(

source: [Can I upload photos but not post to wall in Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873147/can-i-upload-photos-but-not-post-to-wall-in-facebook)

How to contact FB so that they add this VERY important info?

Comment: This is described in Developer Blog post: [Suppressing auto-generated feed stories when uploading photos](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/482/). BTW, It's good to accept your own answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the news feed stream post immediately after upload (if its not returned when you create it). If you call the graph api: https://graph.facebook.com/269434846409322/feed?access_token=... you can get a list of feed posts and then you could issue an HTTP DELETE to the item you want to delete, like https://graph.facebook.com/269434846409322_269690926383714.

Comment: Yeah, that's a workaround I already thought about last night... but  thanks for this idea :)

Comment: Well - somehow this doesn't work. I check if this post already exists and then I delete it. But when in runtime of this script this post doesn't exist - cuz it takes a few seconds/minutes to synchronize to all servers - it won't be deleted. Where can I contact the development team to report this bug?

Comment: Still no helpfull feedback. I created a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/256086114433563?browse=search_4e86db54b30871789483746 - hopefully someone takes a hand on it. It's kinda frustrating - because deleting the posting is not a possibility, because sometimes it takes minutes, until the posting appears. And a cron job for this workaround is ... there must be a better solution :(